# Submenu not working in Server

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, submenu

I recently upload my file from localhost to server. I have `menu - submenu`, It's working well in my `localhost` I don't know what i need to put in here. So i'll put my screenshoot

Here is my menu when i `click` the parent

[image]

My menu should be like this

[image]

Here is my fullpage script `ctrl+u` server fullpage http://pastebin.com/fSgU2WzG and this for my local http://pastebin.com/cHVp9zZN

Comment: .sidebar-menu .treeview-menu {
    display: block;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 5px
}

Answer (score 1):

please check this part it's return 404

`http://store.rpgroup.co.id/assets/template/plugins/jQuery/jquery-2.2.0.min.js`

Comment: Yeah, here is my problem i i change it to `http://store.rpgroup.co.id/assets/template/plugins/jQuery/jQuery-2.2.0.min.js`